# How do I say I Love You in Chinese

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm researching the Chinese language, and I just wanted to know how to say I love you in Chinese. I've got a crush on a guy, and I don't want to say it to where he understands it...it's weird, I know..

Comment: Hopefully I don't have to explain in English...

Comment: Wait, does as you wish mean I love you?

Answer (score 1):

I love you is "我爱你" in Chinese.

Comment: TYSM! I'm going to write this down so I don't forget it!

Comment: By the way, you may also you “我喜欢你” to imply "I like you". Good luck! ^_^